# Can a 1-D risk score (binary outcome) be sensibly used to create multiple treatment groups?

Tags: clustering, prediction

This question concerns predicted probabilities of a binary outcome, and the (I believe) misguided practice of making multiple cutpoints along a one-dimensional risk continuum -- cutpoints that create three or more groups viewed as deserving different treatments.

My contention is that using estimated risk of an event occurring – say, of catching a dangerous virus vs. not catching it—to cluster people into any more than two groups will be misguided and will result in inefficient treatment plans.  Whatever is the favored treatment to reduce negative outcomes among those with the highest scores, that treatment should be applied to everyone above a certain cutpoint, determined by resources.  E.g., if we have the resources to treat only one tenth, then we set a single cutpoint to include one tenth.

Being one-dimensional, the risk score, I contend, can tell us nothing about the best alternative for each person among some set of multiple treatment options.  If we truly want to reduce incidence of infection, we offer the best treatment we have, to everyone we have the resources to treat.

To put it another way, I think it would be illogical to use two cutpoints to create three risk groups (high, medium, and low); to give the high group the most reliable treatment; and to give the medium group some alternative treatment.  What could we expect—-that for the medium group we could get away with *partly* preventing infection?  (Or if infection isn't the best example, think of pregnancy, or mortality.)  Either they will or they won’t catch the virus.  If they do, in this example, they will experience just the same consequences as if they had been in the group marked as high-risk.  The question is, how can limited resources be applied with the greatest effect—-which suggests again that we give the single best treatment to all those with scores above some single cutpoint.

Is my thinking sound?  If not, why not?  If so, what would be the most convincing argument for a layperson to hear?

Comment: Why is this condidered off-topic? decision theory is within statistics ...

Comment: `Either they will or they won’t catch the virus. If they do... they will experience just the same consequences as... the group marked as high-risk`. The same could be said about a low-risk person. If he dies, he dies. It resembles me [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosecutor's_fallacy).

Comment: `we offer the best treatment we have, to everyone we have the resources to treat`. But it is a double-edge weapon. By attempting to soften (I'd say, to conceal) discrimination of people you discriminate out treatments which seem you not "best" and only partly effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would be the most convincing argument for a layperson to hear?

Different types of treatments carry different risks.

Here is an example:

**A sample model:**

For sick patients:

- No treatment has a success rate (spontaneous recovery) of 0.01
- Treatment A has a success rate of 0.80
- Treatment B has a success rate of 0.95

For healthy patients:

- Treatment A can kill a healthy patient with probability 0.01
- Treatment B can kill a healthy patient with probability 0.03

Also assume:

- We can't give both treatments to the same patient
- The risk score is calibrated, hence risk score = *p*(sick).

**Our goal:**

- Find a strategy that maximizes the expected percentage of lives saved, by assigning a treatment to each patient, given his risk score.

**Optimization**:

- The probability of a patient with risk score *p* ending up healthy with no treatment is

  p*0.01 + (1-p)
- The probability of a patient with risk score *p* ending up healthy with treatment A is

  p*0.8 + (1-p)*0.99
- The probability of a patient with risk score *p* ending up healthy with treatment B is

  p*0.95 + (1-p)*0.97

Now, let's plot these three probability functions as a function of *p*:

[image]

It is easy to see the rationale for using 2 cutoff values.

The best treatment is not the same for every patient.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful.  Assuming that treatments carry their own risks, multiple cut points may well be justified.  I'm trying to carry your work forward to simulate events and answer the question of how justified those multiple cutpoints are in the absence of such treatment risks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider you have two treatments available:
1. costs 1000 but has a 99% chance of helping
2. costs 10 but has a 90% chance of working

Would you rather treat 1 with the first, or 100 with the second?

Assume your risk distribution is 1, 0, ..., 0 then you should treat only the first.

If your risk distribution is 0.60,0.599,0.598,0.597,... then you could save over 45 by using the second drug.

There is two points in this model that you may have overlooked:

- Treatments are not guaranteed to work
- Prediction will barely ever be 100% correct

Assume the real risk is 1, 0, ..., 0 as before. But your method did a mistake, and produced the risk scores 0.9, 1.0, 0, ... 0. If you would bet everything on one treatment, you would be treating the wrong person. If you treat the top 100, you have a 90% success chance of curing the one that was really sick in this toy example.

Comment: I'm still thinking through your answer, but "real risk" would have to mean simply "risk," i.e., *predicted* probability.  "Risk distribution" in my example entails fractional numbers on the continuum between 0 and 1.  We would not have risk or "real risk" that consists of only 0s and 1s.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference how you call it, or if it is binary. The point is that predictors make errors, and treatments are not guaranteed to work, and do not have the same cost. You want to minimize cost while maximizing chances of curing a maximum number of people.

Comment: Consider heart issues: pacemaker, or medicine? Why make a binary decision, and treat the top k risk patients with a pacemaker and the other not at all? Instead, form risk groups. Treat high risk with pacemakers, low risk with medicaments, so you can treat more low risk patients if you aren't sure the pacemaker is needed. A single unneeded pacemaker probably means not treating thousand people with medicaments, and maybe saving 10 of them?

Comment: It makes a big difference that the outcome is binary.  Take pregnancy:   it is impossible to halfway prevent it.  Any attempt to do so would result in wasted resources.  It also makes a big difference that the risk score is continuous.

Comment: Looking back at your answer, it brings up points I didn't address but it seems to affirm the idea that whatever treatment is selected, it should be given to everyone who is treated.

Comment: Most contaceptives won't have a 100% success rate. Even if you modeö pregancy as binary - but I'm pretty sure there are some interim conditions where the body isn't "binary pregnant", I believe some animals also have fake pregnancy etc. - it makes your model more capable if you work with probabilities than with final outcomes only.

Comment: No, my model clearly yields that you need to take a succss/cost ratio into account. You don't want go hear this though, and desperately seem to lokk for a reason to claim otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there were three kinds of patient:

- Patients with risk 0 will never catch the virus
- Patients with risk 1 will catch the virus only if untreated
- Patients with risk 2 will always catch the virus

Then the optimal strategy would be to use multiple cutpoints and only treat patients of risk 1.

---

I came up with that pathological example by thinking about decision trees. The model I had in mind was

- A patient of risk *r* arrives
- If they're treated, the probability of infection is $t(r)$.
- If they're not treated, the probability of infection is $u(r)$.

I originally had costs attached to each outcome, but it turns out those aren't important. What's important is that even if you insist that the risk $r$ is 'honest' in that $t(r), u(r)$ are both increasing functions - so higher risk makes for a higher probability of infection - that doesn't mean that the 'benefit' of the treatment $t(r) - u(r)$ has to be increasing with respect to risk.

Comment: Your assumptions remove all uncertainty from the situation.  Of course if we could be certain who was bound to catch the virus then we would absolutely know what action to take for each person.

Comment: I made the probabilities 0 and 1 because I thought it'd make it clearer. The point still holds if the probabilities are say .1/.9/.9 pre-treatment, .1/.1/.9 post-treatment.